# What is the name of the technique of doing object oriented design in JavaScript without class or prototype?

Tags: javascript, oop

Years ago I used this technique because I did not know how to do it "right" with prototype.  It's a technique I call Christmas tree OOD.  You make a function which is like a constructor that makes a new object, attaches new properties to it, like a Christmas tree, and return the reference to it.  Here is an example:

```
function RigidBody() {
    const newRB = document.createElement('canvas');
    
    newRB.dataMember = 5;
  
    newRB.memberFunction = function() {
        // do important rigid body stuff
    }

    return newRB;
}
```

Then you can use this function as a kind of base object to make other derived objects.

```
function Ship(locX, locY) {
    const newShip = new RigidBody();

    newShip.otherDataMember = 34;

    newShip.otherMemberFunction = function() {
        // some other important ship specific stuff to do
    }

    return newShip;
}
```

You can see that this simple thing I did can make N number of objects with a full "class" hierarchy of objects.  Then you can just make an object of the derived object.

```
    const myShip = new Ship(100, 200);
```

I use class now and I don't plan on using this in the future but I'm curious to know if others have used this technique and if it has a name.

Comment: see: [Factory Vs Prototype - What to use when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043279/factory-vs-prototype-what-to-use-when) and [Inheritance with factory method/class pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864114/inheritance-with-factory-method-class-pattern) which links to [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://www.patterns.dev/posts/classic-design-patterns/)

Comment: They say `class` is only `syntax sugar`, it still uses function behind the scenes

Comment: Factory usually means returning potentially N number of different kinds of objects depending on a parameter.  So it's kind of like factory.  This technique definitely works but I would not use it for large programs.

Comment: 1/2 ... **It is a _composition technique_ based on _factory-functions_**. Thus the OP's first mistake is the misuse of a factory as constructor. E.g. `const newShip = new RigidBody();` is not necessary since `newShip` will never be an `instanceof RigidBody`. Despite calling the factory with the `new` operator, just a new canvas element is returned (as intended). No `this` binding is involved. Therefore the OP should rename `RigidBody` to `createRigidBody` which by name tells it's a factory function with no need for `new`.

Comment: 2/2 ... Quite a few people would classify this composition technique already as _**mixin-pattern**_. Some strong believers (non questioning disciples) worship objects created by this quite obvious technique as _"Crockford Objects"_. Others refer to it as [_"Functional Inheritance"_](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/functional-mixins-composing-software-ffb66d5e731c#23ac) (coined by Crockford ) even though a better (not misleading) term could have been e.g. _**Function based Mixins**_ since no inheritance magic is involved, and everything is straightforward object composition/aggregation.

Comment: @JohnVonachen ... The OP might also be interested in reading ... [_"Sharing state when applying Douglas Crockford's composition pattern"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70033960/sharing-state-when-applying-douglas-crockfords-composition-pattern)

Comment: Am I correct in saying that if you created a pile of these objects that you would be using way more memory than is necessary?  And so this technique is fine, parasitic inheritance, but only for small piles of objects.  I think I will just stick to ES6 classes.  I come from the tradition of C++.

Answer (score 1):

It's still called OOP, since you're working with objects. Redefining member functions inside the constructor (when not [necessary for `this`-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)) instead of putting them on the prototype is [considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572), but doesn't change functionality or modelling.

Your technique for creating derived objects is known as [parasitic inheritance](https://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html), a term coined by Douglas Crockford afaict.

Comment: After reading the links you included, especially about parasitic Inheritance I've decided that the way I did it is perfectly kosher.  I did remove the "new"s though.  Thanks.